# Method or Data Member not Found when Creating New Table in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, vb6

The error is showing in this part of the code:

```
dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & Accounts.Label8 & "" & "(Date_today 
TEXT,Time_In TEXT, Lunch_Out TEXT, Lunch_In TEXT, Time_Out TEXT, Status 
TEXT, Notes TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (Date_today));"
```

This is my whole code:

```
Dim dbs As Database

Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Y:\Tempus Beta\Dbase.mdb", False, False, 
";pwd=akgtrxx21")

dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & Accounts.Label8 & "" & "(Date_today TEXT, 
Time_In TEXT, Lunch_Out TEXT, Lunch_In TEXT, Time_Out TEXT, Status TEXT, 
Notes TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (Date_today));"

dbs.Close
```

Is it because its inside a mapped drive `Y:`? (Though my PC has full access to that drive)

Comment: When you debug, what value is contained in `Accounts.Label8`?

Comment: You have to narrow it down. I would capture the string passed to EXECUTE and manually try it in Access. if it works, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Spodger This contains text that i want the table to be named after.

Comment: should be like "anna_prescott"

Comment: actually when its on debug, it only selects the Label8 of Accounts.Label8 and highlights the Private Sub Command1_Click() so when i hover my mouse on accounts.label8, nothing is showing so icant see whats in it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Accounts` is the name of your form, and `Label8` is the name of a label on such form, you should access the content of the label using the **Caption** property, since labels do not have a **Value** property.

Assuming this code resides within an event handler for another control on your form, your code could become:

```vb
dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & Me.Label8.Caption & " (Date_today TEXT, ...
```

Or, to explicitly reference the form:

```vb
dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE " & Forms("Accounts").Controls("Label8").Caption & " (Date_today TEXT, ...
```

Comment: actually, sorry i found the error, it has something to do with another form name i have on my project named "Database" that's why it show error on the line

    `Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Y:\Tempus Beta\Dbase.mdb", False, False, 
    ";pwd=akgtrxx21")`


all is good now, thank you :)